# Cannot create POST in Postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing, postman

I was creating an API and testing it with post man when I started to make new products in it.

```
module.exports.create = function(req, res){
    const newProduct = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        quantity: req.body.quantity
    });
    newProduct.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            res.send('New product added successfully.');
        }
    });
}
```

This is the create controller
and this one below is my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// creating the product schema
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    quantity: Number
},{
    versionKey: false
});

// creating a new model called "Product"
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

Whenever I try to go to localhost:8000/create it shows cannot post/create
and also my database shows this error in atlas:

> [MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
> API is live on http://localhost:3000/products

The route declaration:

```
// to get all the products 
router.get('/', productsController.products);
// to create a product 
router.post('/create', productsController.create);
```

Comment: Show the route declaration

Comment: // to get all the products
router.get('/', productsController.products);

// to create a product
router.post('/create', productsController.create);